# How to solve the Next Greater Element in an array [ Not The First Next Greater Element] to the right?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, stack, logic

Previously There are some posts to solve this problem but they are providing solution for the **First Next Greater Element to the right** rather than the **Next Greater Element to the right** .

Suppose the input array is `[4, 15, 2, 9, 20, 11, 13 ,16 ,3]`

The Next Greater Element to the right output is

```
4 -> 9 ,
15 -> 16 ,
2->3 ,
9->11 ,
20->-1 ,
11->13 ,
13->16 ,
16->-1 ,
3->-1 ,
```

The First Next Greater Element Output is like

```
4->15 ,
15->20 ,
2->9 ,
9->20 ,
20->-1
11->13
13-> 16
16-> -1
3-> -1
```

I hope you guys have understood the difference.

Almost all online sources[Up to my knowledge] have provided solution for the second case.

I want the solution [ Algorithm ] for the First case in optimistic manner 
[ < O(n^2) ]

Any type of data structure is fine for me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: if the input case contains [12, 11,13] ,
Sorting will lead to [11,12,13 ] . So the answer is 12 but it is actually 13 [The next greater element to the right]

Comment: Right, sorting wont solve the problem. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called the surpasser problem.  It can be solved by putting the items in revese order (i.e. from last to first) into a self-balancing BST. After you insert a node into the tree, you can find its next greater element by looking at the smallest element in the subtree of its right child, or (if it doesn't have a right child), the next greater element is the first ancestor that the node belongs to its left subtree (the first ancestor greater than the inserted node).

Complexity: O(n log n)

There is an alternative solution using am algorithm similar to merge sort.

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27823253/binary-search-solution-for-max-number-of-surpassers)

Comment: Great Idea...!! Thanks :)